# How to list all AWS S3 objects in a bucket using Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

What is the simplest way to get a list of all items within an S3 bucket using Java?

```
List<S3ObjectSummary> s3objects = s3.listObjects(bucketName,prefix).getObjectSummaries();
```

This example only returns 1000 items.

Comment: The question should be edited to provide the S3 package and version that you are using.

Comment: This worked for me: http://codeflex.co/get-list-of-objects-from-s3-directory/

Comment: How they could hardcode 1000 files limit. This is so bug prone, I need to fix my production now.

Comment: this is also awesome link- https://www.baeldung.com/aws-s3-java

Comment: One can check this if they are not able to list objects/files in a specific folder https://stackoverflow.com/a/68481553/8874958

Answer (score 140, accepted):

It might be a workaround but this solved my problem:

```
ObjectListing listing = s3.listObjects( bucketName, prefix );
List<S3ObjectSummary> summaries = listing.getObjectSummaries();

while (listing.isTruncated()) {
   listing = s3.listNextBatchOfObjects (listing);
   summaries.addAll (listing.getObjectSummaries());
}
```

Comment: Doesn't look like a workaround to me, that seems to be the intended use of the API.

Comment: Someone suggested [this](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/253044) edit to your answer, if you're interested

Comment: s3.listObjects has a default limit of 1000 elements per listing, so as @JoachimSauer said this is the intended use of the API

Comment: is it possible to get version info at the same time?

Comment: This makes the dangerous assumption that the `List` returned by `getObjectSummaries()` is mutable.

Comment: Try to write a unit test for this piece of code, set maxKeys to 10 and try to list all your 20 keys, `truncated` will be false after listing those 10 keys for some reason and the unit test will fail on returning only 10 keys ...

Comment: #Steve Kuo above is correct.  I got an exception when I tried to add to the summaries list.  I had to make my own list.

Comment: May i know what is the prefix here?

Comment: @VeerendarCharyMunigadapa `prefix` acts like a filter, but it only considers filenames starting with that string `prefix`

Answer (score 63):

For those, who are reading this in 2018+. There are two new pagination-hassle-free APIs available: one in AWS SDK for Java 1.x and another one in 2.x.

## 1.x

There is a [new API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/iterable/S3Objects.html) in Java SDK that allows you to iterate through objects in S3 bucket without dealing with pagination:

```
AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard().build();

S3Objects.inBucket(s3, "the-bucket").forEach((S3ObjectSummary objectSummary) -> {
    // TODO: Consume `objectSummary` the way you need
    System.out.println(objectSummary.key);
});
```

This iteration is lazy:

> The list of [`S3ObjectSummary`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3ObjectSummary.html)s will be fetched lazily, a page at a time, as they are needed. The size of the page can be controlled with the [`withBatchSize(int)`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/iterable/S3Objects.html#withBatchSize-int-) method.

## 2.x

The API changed, so here is an SDK 2.x version:

```
S3Client client = S3Client.builder().region(Region.US_EAST_1).build();
ListObjectsV2Request request = ListObjectsV2Request.builder().bucket("the-bucket").prefix("the-prefix").build();
ListObjectsV2Iterable response = client.listObjectsV2Paginator(request);

for (ListObjectsV2Response page : response) {
    page.contents().forEach((S3Object object) -> {
        // TODO: Consume `object` the way you need
        System.out.println(object.key());
    });
}
```

[`ListObjectsV2Iterable`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/index.html?software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/paginators/ListObjectsV2Iterable.html) is lazy as well:

> When the operation is called, an instance of this class is returned. At this point, no service calls are made yet and so there is no guarantee that the request is valid. As you iterate through the iterable, SDK will start lazily loading response pages by making service calls until there are no pages left or your iteration stops. If there are errors in your request, you will see the failures only after you start iterating through the iterable.

Comment: Awesome answer helped a lot, but I'd like to ask more information.
I want to iterate over the pages like Spring Pageable, e.g. request the first 20 objects and if I need I could request the second page with the 20 next. Is it possible?

Comment: FWIW in the 1.x API replace the `inBucket` call with `withPrefix` if required.

Comment: is it worth noting that the `listObjectsV2Paginator` method on the `S3Client` behaves as you have stated, BUT the same method on the `S3AsyncClient` actually gives you back a `org.reactivestreams.Publisher<ListObjectsV2Response>` which you can convert easily into a `Flux` and `flatMapIterable` into the S3 objects.

Why is this good? Because it can pre-fetch pages on demand and back off on back-pressure. So once you finish a page you don't wait for the next page to be requested internally. It's "quicker" or "smoother". (N.B. they had a bug with their own `flatMapIterable` method I reported)

Answer (score 32):

This is direct from AWS documentation:

```
AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());        

ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest()
    .withBucketName(bucketName)
    .withPrefix("m");
ObjectListing objectListing;

do {
        objectListing = s3client.listObjects(listObjectsRequest);
        for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : 
            objectListing.getObjectSummaries()) {
            System.out.println( " - " + objectSummary.getKey() + "  " +
                    "(size = " + objectSummary.getSize() + 
                    ")");
        }
        listObjectsRequest.setMarker(objectListing.getNextMarker());
} while (objectListing.isTruncated());
```

Answer (score 13):

I am processing a large collection of objects generated by our system; we changed the format of the stored data and needed to check each file, determine which ones were in the old format, and convert them. There are other ways to do this, but this one relates to your question.

```
    ObjectListing list = amazonS3Client.listObjects(contentBucketName, contentKeyPrefix);

    do {                

        List<S3ObjectSummary> summaries = list.getObjectSummaries();

        for (S3ObjectSummary summary : summaries) {

            String summaryKey = summary.getKey();               

            /* Retrieve object */

            /* Process it */

        }

        list = amazonS3Client.listNextBatchOfObjects(list);

    }while (list.isTruncated());
```

Answer (score 10):

Listing Keys Using the AWS SDK for Java

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingObjectKeysUsingJava.html

```
import java.io.IOException;
import com.amazonaws.AmazonClientException;
import com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ListObjectsRequest;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ListObjectsV2Request;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ListObjectsV2Result;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectListing;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.S3ObjectSummary;

public class ListKeys {
    private static String bucketName = "***bucket name***";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        AmazonS3 s3client = new AmazonS3Client(new ProfileCredentialsProvider());
        try {
            System.out.println("Listing objects");
            final ListObjectsV2Request req = new ListObjectsV2Request().withBucketName(bucketName);
            ListObjectsV2Result result;
            do {               
               result = s3client.listObjectsV2(req);

               for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : 
                   result.getObjectSummaries()) {
                   System.out.println(" - " + objectSummary.getKey() + "  " +
                           "(size = " + objectSummary.getSize() + 
                           ")");
               }
               System.out.println("Next Continuation Token : " + result.getNextContinuationToken());
               req.setContinuationToken(result.getNextContinuationToken());
            } while(result.isTruncated() == true ); 

         } catch (AmazonServiceException ase) {
            System.out.println("Caught an AmazonServiceException, " +
                    "which means your request made it " +
                    "to Amazon S3, but was rejected with an error response " +
                    "for some reason.");
            System.out.println("Error Message:    " + ase.getMessage());
            System.out.println("HTTP Status Code: " + ase.getStatusCode());
            System.out.println("AWS Error Code:   " + ase.getErrorCode());
            System.out.println("Error Type:       " + ase.getErrorType());
            System.out.println("Request ID:       " + ase.getRequestId());
        } catch (AmazonClientException ace) {
            System.out.println("Caught an AmazonClientException, " +
                    "which means the client encountered " +
                    "an internal error while trying to communicate" +
                    " with S3, " +
                    "such as not being able to access the network.");
            System.out.println("Error Message: " + ace.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

As a slightly more concise solution to listing S3 objects when they might be truncated:

```
ListObjectsRequest request = new ListObjectsRequest().withBucketName(bucketName);
ObjectListing listing = null;

while((listing == null) || (request.getMarker() != null)) {
  listing = s3Client.listObjects(request);
  // do stuff with listing
  request.setMarker(listing.getNextMarker());
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Gray your solution was strange but you seem like a nice guy.

```
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new BasicAWSCredentials( ....

ObjectListing images = s3Client.listObjects(bucketName); 

List<S3ObjectSummary> list = images.getObjectSummaries();
for(S3ObjectSummary image: list) {
    S3Object obj = s3Client.getObject(bucketName, image.getKey());
    writeToFile(obj.getObjectContent());
}
```

Comment: as far as I can tell this solution will only take the firs 1000 kyes/files and print them. But does not further iterate for more files.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but this still might be usefull to anyone: The Java/Android SDK on version 2.1 provides a method called setMaxKeys. Like this:

```
s3objects.setMaxKeys(arg0)
```

You probably found a solution by now, but please check one answer as correct so that it might help others in the future.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me.

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            List<String> listing = getObjectNamesForBucket(bucket, s3Client);
            Log.e(TAG, "listing "+ listing);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e(TAG, "Exception found while listing "+ e);
        }
    }
});

thread.start();



  private List<String> getObjectNamesForBucket(String bucket, AmazonS3 s3Client) {
        ObjectListing objects=s3Client.listObjects(bucket);
        List<String> objectNames=new ArrayList<String>(objects.getObjectSummaries().size());
        Iterator<S3ObjectSummary> oIter=objects.getObjectSummaries().iterator();
        while (oIter.hasNext()) {
            objectNames.add(oIter.next().getKey());
        }
        while (objects.isTruncated()) {
            objects=s3Client.listNextBatchOfObjects(objects);
            oIter=objects.getObjectSummaries().iterator();
            while (oIter.hasNext()) {
                objectNames.add(oIter.next().getKey());
            }
        }
        return objectNames;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to list all 1000 object in your bucket at a time. A more robust solution will be to fetch a max of 10 objects at a time. You can do this with the [withMaxKeys](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ListObjectsV2Request.html#withMaxKeys-java.lang.Integer-) method.

The following code creates an S3 client, fetches 10 or less objects at a time and filters based  on a prefix and generates a [pre-signed url](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html) for the fetched object:

```
import com.amazonaws.HttpMethod;
import com.amazonaws.SdkClientException;
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSStaticCredentialsProvider;
import com.amazonaws.auth.BasicAWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.regions.Regions;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3ClientBuilder;
import com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.*;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Date;

/**
 * @author shabab
 * @since 21 Sep, 2020
 */
public class AwsMain {

    static final String ACCESS_KEY = "";
    static final String SECRET = "";
    static final Regions BUCKET_REGION = Regions.DEFAULT_REGION;
    static final String BUCKET_NAME = "";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        BasicAWSCredentials awsCreds = new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET);

        try {
            final AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                    .standard()
                    .withRegion(BUCKET_REGION)
                    .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(awsCreds))
                    .build();

            ListObjectsV2Request req = new ListObjectsV2Request().withBucketName(BUCKET_NAME).withMaxKeys(10);
            ListObjectsV2Result result;

            do {
                result = s3Client.listObjectsV2(req);

                result.getObjectSummaries()
                        .stream()
                        .filter(s3ObjectSummary -> {
                            return s3ObjectSummary.getKey().contains("Market-subscriptions/")
                                    && !s3ObjectSummary.getKey().equals("Market-subscriptions/");
                        })
                        .forEach(s3ObjectSummary -> {

                            GeneratePresignedUrlRequest generatePresignedUrlRequest =
                                    new GeneratePresignedUrlRequest(BUCKET_NAME, s3ObjectSummary.getKey())
                                            .withMethod(HttpMethod.GET)
                                            .withExpiration(getExpirationDate());

                            URL url = s3Client.generatePresignedUrl(generatePresignedUrlRequest);

                            System.out.println(s3ObjectSummary.getKey() + " Pre-Signed URL: " + url.toString());
                        });

                String token = result.getNextContinuationToken();
                req.setContinuationToken(token);

            } while (result.isTruncated());
        } catch (SdkClientException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private static Date getExpirationDate() {
        Date expiration = new java.util.Date();
        long expTimeMillis = expiration.getTime();
        expTimeMillis += 1000 * 60 * 60;
        expiration.setTime(expTimeMillis);

        return expiration;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using **SDK V2** reactive streams integrations with **automatic pagination** as described in the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/pagination.html)

This example uses [project reactor](https://projectreactor.io/) implementation of the reactive streams standard but it also works with other implementation (e.g., RxJava)

```
    ListObjectsV2Request listObjects = ListObjectsV2Request
            .builder()
            .bucket("<bucketName>")
            .maxKeys(100) // Number of items per page. Using pagination to get all objects in the bucket.
            .build();

    // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/pagination.html
    // Auto-pagination method that makes multiple service calls to get the next page of results automatically.
    // Publish messages by batches to sqs as they come from s3 pagination result.
    return Flux.from(s3Client.listObjectsV2Paginator(listObjects))
            .flatMap(list -> Flux.fromIterable(list.contents())
                    .map(s3Object -> transformObject(s3Object))
                    .collectList()
                    .flatMap(sqsPublisher::publishBatch))
            .doOnError(e -> log.error("Failed to blabla", e))
            .then();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AmazonS3 s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                             .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
                             .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(new BasicAWSCredentials(getAccessKey(), getSecretKey())))
                             .build();

List<String> s3Keys = s3Client.listObjects("bucketName")
            .getObjectSummaries().stream().map(S3ObjectSummary::getKey)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ListObjectsV2Request request = ListObjectsV2Request.builder().bucket("bucketName").prefix("your-prefix").build();
ListObjectsV2Iterable response = s3.listObjectsV2Paginator(request);
for (ListObjectsV2Response page : response) {
    page.contents().forEach((S3Object object) -> {
       // TODO: Consume `object` the way you need
   })
```

use awsV2 s3paginatorListObject in doc(https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/javav2/example_code/s3/src/main/java/com/example/s3/ListObjectsPaginated.java)

Answer (score -3):

Try this one out

```
public void getObjectList(){
        System.out.println("Listing objects");
        ObjectListing objectListing = s3.listObjects(new ListObjectsRequest()
                .withBucketName(bucketName)
                .withPrefix("ads"));
        for (S3ObjectSummary objectSummary : objectListing.getObjectSummaries()) {
            System.out.println(" - " + objectSummary.getKey() + "  " +
                               "(size = " + objectSummary.getSize() + ")");
        }
    }
```

You can all the objects within the bucket with specific prefix.

Comment: no u cant, only 1000 files limit, did u not read above, your solution has the same issue