# How to list AWS S3 objects and versions in a versioned bucket using Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would like retrieve a list of all objects in a versioned bucket along with their versions in a list similar to how the AWS S3 Console does it:

[image: AWS S3 Console]

I am able to list objects in a non-versioned bucket using the advice from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027265/how-to-list-all-aws-s3-objects-in-a-bucket-using-java) SO question.  However, it is not all that clear how to list them along with version IDs as `S3ObjectSummary` contains no versioning information.  It would seem cumbersome to make separate calls to versioning methods and then try to put them together with the information contained within an `S3ObjectSummary`

Answer (score 4):

This looks like the closest answer I could find so far:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/list-obj-version-enabled-bucket.html

The relevant code snippet is here:

```
    ListVersionsRequest request = new ListVersionsRequest()
        .withBucketName(bucketName)
        .withMaxResults(2);
        // you can specify .withPrefix to obtain version list for a specific object or objects with 
        // the specified key prefix.

    VersionListing versionListing;            
    do {
        versionListing = s3client.listVersions(request);
        for (S3VersionSummary objectSummary : 
            versionListing.getVersionSummaries()) {
            System.out.println(" - " + objectSummary.getKey() + "  " +
                    "(size = " + objectSummary.getSize() + ")" +
                    "(versionID= " + objectSummary.getVersionId() + ")");

        }
        request.setKeyMarker(versionListing.getNextKeyMarker());
        request.setVersionIdMarker(versionListing.getNextVersionIdMarker());
    } while (versionListing.isTruncated());
```