# Find position of an item in an S3 Bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am able to easily grab individual items from my S3 Bucket using Java, and get the object metadata, but there seems to be no easy way to grab the position of the object in the bucket. Here are the things that I do know:

* [There is a workaround in place to list all the objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027265/how-to-list-all-aws-s3-objects-in-a-bucket-using-java)

* [There is some sort of marker system in place for continuing ListObjectRequests](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/ObjectListing.html#getMarker--)

But what would be the easiest/most optimal way to figure out what my position is alphabetically from the end of the list?

At this point, the solution seems to be fairly convoluted

```
public JSONObject objectPosition(String key) {
  ObjectListing listing = CLIENT.listObjects( bucketName, prefix );
  List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();
  List<S3ObjectSummary> summaries   = listing.getObjectSummaries();

  while (listing.isTruncated()) {
     for(S3ObjectSummary s3o : summaries) {
       keys.add(s3o.getKey());
      }
    listing = CLIENT.listNextBatchOfObjects (listing);
    summaries   = listing.getObjectSummaries();
  }

  JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();
  jo.put("totalSize", Integer.toString(keys.size()));
  jo.put("position", Integer.toString(key.indexOf(key)));
  return jo;
}
```

But this means that every time my endpoint is touched, I not only have to query the s3 for all of the objects and their keys, but then I have to find the key I need to check the position of in a large list. Unfortunately local persistence between calls is not an option - so perhaps placing some sort of size file within the s3 bucket is the solution?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have some code examples to provide more context?

Comment: By position of object what do you mean?

Comment: @SeanNieuwoudt, I've updated the question to include what I've written thus far

Comment: The listings are in returned in *lexical* order.  An object's "position" changes relative to the beginning if lexically "earlier" (lesser) object is added or deleted or changes relative to the end if a lexically "later" (greater) but the "position" is not a meaningful piece of information.  What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot, I'm attempting to track my progress creating objects from the S3 files, and as I go through creating objects from these files, I'd like to know my progress. No S3 files are being added or deleted in this operation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position of an object is its prefix and name lexically relative to the other object prefixes and names, as Michael-sqlbot mentioned.  You would need to list all the objects to get all the object's positions.
Instead, try to track the changes to your bucket contents rather than polling/scanning for endpoint changes.  Scanning your bucket will incur S3 List API call charges.
You might try enabling S3 Events, then a file create/delete event could trigger an AWS Lamba written in Python or other language, to process or save the paths that have changed in your bucket.  The first 1 million Lamba executions per month are free.