# Printing all keys of files and folders recursively doesn't work as expected

Tags: amazon-web-services

We have stored several files an folders in Amazon S3.

We are using the following code to iterate all the files and folders for the given root folder

```
ObjectListing listing = s3.listObjects( bucketName, prefix );
List<S3ObjectSummary> summaries = listing.getObjectSummaries();
while (listing.isTruncated()) {
   listing = s3.listNextBatchOfObjects (listing);
   summaries.addAll (listing.getObjectSummaries());
}
```

Assume the root folder has 1000 files and 10 folders. One of the folder has 100 sub-folder and each has 500 files.

The above program works fine and list all the files and traverse all the files.

The problem is it is not printing the keys of all the sub-folder.

The interesting thing is it prints the first sub-folder

example

```
Root Folder: Emp
Folder Under Root folder: FolderA, FolderB, FolderC
Sub-folder under FolderA: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ... 100
Each 0 or 1 or 2...has 500 files each
```

What could be the problem? Any limitation in AWS or Folder should not be numeric or is there is any logical issue?

When used the above code.

FolderA/0/ is coming as key where as FolderA/1....FolderA/10 doesn't come

Thanks.

Comment: There is no such thing as folders in S3. You can create pseudo-folders via the web console, which actually creates an empty object with that key, which is probably what you are seeing for the few folders that are working as you expect.

Comment: yes..i need all the empty objects i.e folders under the sub-folder.

Comment: The code looks like it's the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027265/how-to-list-all-aws-s3-objects-in-a-bucket-using-java . Step through your code and verify it's looping properly. Also, double check your results: they may be correct, but you think they're wrong.

Comment: Matt Houser, it is not working 100%. sub-level folder are left in my case. not sure whether it is a rare case. i named the folder with numerics alone

Comment: To confirm, "FolderA/1" should be a folder? If so, are there any objects in the "FolderA/1" folder? If so, are you getting those objects?

Comment: Yes. I am getting FolderA/0/file1...FolderA/0/file100 where as FolderA/1 is not able to be retrieved where as FolderA/1/file1....FolderA/1/file100 able to print.problem with printing or getting the keys

Comment: Then please read my answer again. It addresses this issue exactly.

Comment: "problem with printing or getting the keys" ... neither. The problem is the folder key does not exist. So you must determine the folder yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as folders or directories in Amazon S3. Amazon S3 is a key-data store. Folders and sub-folders are a human interpretation of the "/" character in object keys. S3 doesn't know or care about them.

You can "fake" the creation of an empty folder in S3 by creating a 0-byte object that ends with the "/" character.

When iterating over the list of objects, these 0-byte "folders" will be included.

However, you may also have objects such as "folder1/object1" where in your mind, "folder1" is a sub-folder off the root. But in S3, there may not be such an object as "folder1/". In this case, you will not see "folder1/" outputted in your result list on it's own.

If you need to get a list of all "sub-folders", then you need to not only look for objects that end with the "/" character, but you also need to examine all objects for a "/" character and infer a sub-folder from the object's key because there may not be that 0-byte object for the folder itself.

For example:

- folder1/object1
- folder2/
- folder2/object1

In this example, there's only one sub-folder object, but you could say there are actually two sub-folders.

**Java-ish psuedo-code to get sub-folders:**

```
function getSubFolders(bucketName, currentFolder)
{
  // Use the current folder as the S3 prefix
  var prefix = currentFolder;

  // Get all objects
  ObjectListing listing = s3.listObjects( bucketName, prefix );
  List<S3ObjectSummary> summaries = listing.getObjectSummaries();
  while (listing.isTruncated()) {
    listing = s3.listNextBatchOfObjects (listing);
    summaries.addAll (listing.getObjectSummaries());
  }

  // Split the list into files in the current folder and sub-folders
  List<string> subFolders = new List<string>();
  List<string> files = new List<string>();
  foreach (var summary in summaries)
  {
    var key = summary.key;

    // The key includes the prefix, so remove it
    key = key.subString(prefix.length);

    // If the key includes a / character, then
    // it's in a subfolder. Just save the subfolder part
    // of this object.
    // Otherwise, save the key in our list of files.
    var slashIndex = key.indexOf("/");
    if (slashIndex >= 0)
    {
      subFolders.add(key.subString(0, slashIndex));
    }
    else
    {
      files.add(key);
    }
  }

  // Remove duplicate entries from our subFolder list
  subFolders = subFolders.distinct();
}
```

Comment: When we browse through S3 browser or cloud berry or cyberduck we able to see all the folder...When we iterate the same over using the above code and printing the keys. the folder names are not printed. Please help me as i just need all the names which is being shown in the other browsers or explorers

Comment: Those other programs are inferring sub-folders from the existing object keys. Exactly what I'm saying in my answer. You need to look at all objects and build your own sub-folder list.

Comment: Matt House..How to achieve it via code. can you please help me with the code or modify the above to get the results, please?

Comment: I've added some java-ish pseudo-code. It could be better optimized, but it should give you an idea.

Comment: Matt Houser. This is not going to solve the issue as the object summary itself not coming for the couple of folders specified

Comment: @Kathire Please include a concrete example in your question. Please include some sample keys included, and the folder you're not seeing.

Answer (score 0):

The folder with numeric characters are not populated recursively properly.

Currently resolved as follows

1. Iterating all folder under a path .
2. Iterating all the files under a path recursively.

Getting all the files and folders recursively doesn't work. However processing folders separating when we iterate it recursively works fine.

This seems to be little bit expensive operation but it works.