# How to get all the folder keys recursively?

Tags: amazon-s3

I want to get all the folder keys recusively without files.

Example,
FolderA
FolderA/FolderB
FolderA/FolderB/FolderC
FolderC
FolderD

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Kathire. Can you please explain how this is not a duplicate of your previous question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38923661/printing-all-keys-of-files-and-folders-recursively-doesnt-work-as-expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although S3 does not have a concept of "folder" (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2141499/2491766)), it lets you perform hierarchical operations using ["prefix" and "delimiter"](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ListingKeysHierarchy.html).

You can look at the Java API [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#listObjects-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ListObjectsRequest-).