# Find/Delete S3 object based on substring of object key

Tags: java, amazon-s3

Is it possible to find/delete S3 object if we only have part of the object key?

**Scenario :** Let say user store `123123.jpeg` in S3 (bucket name : mybucket) and I need to delete this object but I only know `123123`, not the whole key with the extension `.jpeg`.

I'm aware that we can find object in a bucket based on **prefix** but AFAIK this only apply if the object exist in path inside the bucket, eg : `mybucket/imgpath/123123.jpeg`

Comment: Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027265/how-to-list-all-aws-s3-objects-in-a-bucket-using-java

Answer (score 1):

You can use brute force:

```
List<String> matchingKeys = new ArrayList<>();
Predicate<String> predicate = Pattern.compile(".*/" + filename + "\\.\\w+").asPredicate();
for (ObjectListing listing = s3.listObjects(bucketName, "/");; listing = s3.listNextBatchOfObjects(listing)) {
    listing.getObjectSummaries().stream()
      .map(S3ObjectSummary::getKey)
      .filter(predicate)
      .forEach(matchingKeys::add);
    if (!listing.isTruncated()) {
        break;
    }
}
```

Instead of collecting the hits, you could just delete:

```
.forEach(key -> s3.deleteObject(bucketName, key));
```

Note: This uses a regex suitable for your scenario of finding a key given the extension-less filename, but you could adjust the regex as you need. For example, to find all keys that have a substring *anywhere* in their key, use the regex

```
".*" + substring ".*"
```

Or case insensitive

```
"(?i).*" + substring ".*"
```

etc.

<sub>Disclaimer: Code may not compile or work as it was thumbed in on my phone (but there's a reasonable chance it will work)</sub>