# Not all data (only 1000 elements) retrieved from S3 using Amazon SDK

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a problem with retrieving the data from S3 using Amazon SDK. The problem is that it retrieves only 1000 elements, while indeed I have 10,000 elements in the `aws_bucket_data` -> `currentDataDirectory`. I do not use `setMaxKeys(...)`, so the result seems to be weird.

```
BasicAWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials("...", "...");
        client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);

ListObjectsRequest listObjectsRequest = new ListObjectsRequest()
                    .withBucketName(aws_bucket_data)
                    .withPrefix(currentDataDirectory);

ObjectListing objectListing = client.listObjects(listObjectsRequest);

System.out.println(objectListing.getObjectSummaries().size());
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AWS S3 API has a limit of maximum 1000 keys per response.

You will have to do multiple requests to retrieve all of your objects.

You can take a look at the API here:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGET.html

I have found a example to retrieve all your objects:

[How to list all AWS S3 objects in a bucket using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027265/how-to-list-all-aws-s3-objects-in-a-bucket-using-java)

Comment: I would love to, but I am currently not at home, so I cannot provide you with more detailed code snippet. There are however a lot of topics about this subject, if you just google a bit. I would love to give you more details, but I cannot do that atm.

Comment: I have added a stackoverflow link with an example

Comment: I finally used this: `do { ... if (response.isTruncated())
                {
                    request.setMarker(response.getNextMarker());
                }
                else
                {
                    request = null;
                }
            } while (request != null);`