# AWS SDK V2 S3 fetch object is not fetching objects more than 1000

Tags: java, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am using AWS SDK version : 2.16.78. But the `ListObjectsRequest` object is not fetching objects more than 1000.

I did go through the documentation but I wasn't able to find how to set the continuous token.
I am using the below code snippet

```
 try {
        ListObjectsRequest listObjects = ListObjectsRequest
                .builder()
                .bucket(bucketName)
                .build();

        ListObjectsResponse res = s3.listObjects(listObjects);
        List<S3Object> objects = res.contents();

        for (ListIterator iterVals = objects.listIterator(); iterVals.hasNext(); ) {
            S3Object myValue = (S3Object) iterVals.next();
            System.out.print("\n The name of the key is " + myValue.key());
         }

    } catch (S3Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
        System.exit(1);
    }
```

The above code is only fetching 1000 s3 objects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you indicated, AWS will only [return up to 1000 of the objects in a bucket](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_ListObjects.html):

> Returns some or all (up to 1,000) of the objects in a bucket.

Amazon S3 lists objects in alphabetical order. You can take advantage of this fact and provide a [marker](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/) to the key that should be used to start with in the next requests, if [appropriate](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/model/ListObjectsResponse.html#isTruncated--):

```java
try {

  ListObjectsRequest listObjects = ListObjectsRequest
    .builder()
    .bucket(bucketName)
      .build()
  ;

  ListObjectsResponse listObjectsResponse = null;
  String lastKey = null;

  do {
    if ( listObjectsResponse != null ) {
      listObjectsRequest = listObjectsRequest.toBuilder()
         .marker(lastKey)
           .build()
      ; 
    }

    listObjectsResponse = s3.listObjects(listObjectsRequest); 

    List<S3Object> objects = listObjectsResponse.contents();

    // Iterate over results
    for (ListIterator iterVals = objects.listIterator();    iterVals.hasNext(); ) {
      S3Object myValue = (S3Object) iterVals.next();
      String key = myValue.key();
      System.out.print("\n The name of the key is " + key);
      // Update the value of the last key processed
      lastKey = key;
    }
  } while ( listObjectsResponse.isTruncated() );
} catch (S3Exception e) {
  System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
  System.exit(1);
}
```

Something very similar can be achieved with the v2 of the list objects API `ListObjectsV2Request` [`startAfter`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/model/ListObjectsV2Request.Builder.html#startAfter-java.lang.String-) method.

With v2, you can use `ListObjectsV2Response` and continuation token as well. Something similar to:

```java
try {

  ListObjectsV2Request listObjects = ListObjectsV2Request
    .builder()
    .bucket(bucketName)
      .build()
  ;

  ListObjectsV2Response listObjectsResponse = null;
  String nextContinuationToken = null;

  do {
    if ( listObjectsResponse != null ) {
      listObjectsRequest = listObjectsRequest.toBuilder()
         .continuationToken(nextContinuationToken)
           .build()
      ; 
    }

    listObjectsResponse = s3.listObjectsV2(listObjectsRequest); 
    nextContinuationToken = listObjectsResponse.nextContinuationToken();

    List<S3Object> objects = listObjectsResponse.contents();

    // Iterate over results
    for (ListIterator iterVals = objects.listIterator();    iterVals.hasNext(); ) {
      S3Object myValue = (S3Object) iterVals.next();
      String key = myValue.key();
      System.out.print("\n The name of the key is " + key);
    }
  } while ( listObjectsResponse.isTruncated() );
} catch (S3Exception e) {
  System.err.println(e.awsErrorDetails().errorMessage());
  System.exit(1);
}
```

Finally, you can use the [`listObjectsV2Paginator`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/s3/S3Client.html#listObjectsV2Paginator-software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.ListObjectsV2Request-) method to iterate over the results in a similar way like `listNextBatchOfObjects` was used in the v1 of the API. See for instance [this related v1 code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/f935a3758b771a25f628f1d296cb61044a82b4ac/aws-java-sdk-s3/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/s3/transfer/TransferManager.java#L1352-L1511) and these [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44070580/not-all-data-only-1000-elements-retrieved-from-s3-using-amazon-sdk/44070675) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027265/how-to-list-all-aws-s3-objects-in-a-bucket-using-java) related SO questions.

All the mappings between operations from v1 and v2 versions of the API are documented [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java-v2/blob/c9c33fb57a414f5417e6607f7f5e0d27cae37423/docs/LaunchChangelog.md#411-s3-operation-migration).

Comment: @Rushikesh Sabde I edited the answer with a minor code change, sorry for the inconveniences.

Comment: Suggestion of passing marker of lastKey works. Thanks. (I think you mean `lastKey = myValue.key()` instead of `lastKey = object.key()`?)

Comment: You are welcome @DianaEftaiha, and thank you very much,  yes, the code is like you indicated: thank you for point that out.