# List files in s3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

There are around 6000+ files in my S3 bucket, Im using trying to list the files in S3 using java

```
ListObjectsV2Request req = new ListObjectsV2Request().withBucketName("a205718-troa-published-content-bucket-us-east-1-ppe").withPrefix("all/full/");

ListObjectsV2Result listing = s3Client.listObjectsV2(req);
System.out.print(listing.getKeyCount());
```

Im getting keycount as 1000 only.

what to do in order to get all the files in S3?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to list all AWS S3 objects in a bucket using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027265/how-to-list-all-aws-s3-objects-in-a-bucket-using-java)

Answer (score 2):

To quote the documentation:

> Because buckets can contain a virtually unlimited number of keys, the
>   complete results of a list query can be extremely large. To manage
>   large result sets, Amazon S3 uses pagination to split them into
>   multiple responses. Always check the `ObjectListing.isTruncated()`
>   method to see if the returned listing is complete or if additional
>   calls are needed to get more results.